# How to set verical progressBar color depending on percent of progress?

Tags: android, kotlin

is there any solution how to put a progressBar color depending on percent of progress? For example if my progressBar 0-5% it's red, if it's 5-50% it's yellow. If it's 50-100% it's green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the progress you can also set the color of it. For API 21+;

```
val progress = (0..100).random()
progressBar.apply {
    this.progress = progress
    progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
        when {
            progress <= 5 -> Color.RED
            progress in 6..50 -> Color.YELLOW
            else -> Color.GREEN
        }
    )
}
```

EDIT based on max progress 14 and current progress 7

```
val maxProgress = 14
val currentProgress = 7
val fixedProgress = (100.0 / maxProgress * currentProgress).roundToInt()
progressBar.apply {
    max = maxProgress
    progress = currentProgress
    progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
        when {
            fixedProgress <= 5 -> Color.RED
            fixedProgress in 6..50 -> Color.YELLOW
            else -> Color.GREEN
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What if i have variable which set the length of max progress? So my max progress always different

Comment: Depends on your implementation but based on this example: `progressBar.progress = progress / 100 * maxProgress` and `progressBar.max = maxProgress`

Comment: I didn't really get your example to be honest. For example my max progress is 14. My progress right now is 7 which is half of my max progress. How can i make my programm understand that we are on half of the progress and make it yellow?

Comment: I needed more detail of your implementation, now that you've provided it I've edited the answer

Comment: If i'm not bored you I have one more question. I made your code fit to my programm. It's cool but i want to change image in my ImageView with progressBar. I tried to make this code but it's not working and i know why. That's why we are making this "when" in "ColorStateList". But can we fix it to make it work again? :)

Comment: progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
        when {
                 fixedProgress <= 7 -> {
                    Color.RED
                    bindingClass.imgLensActing.setImageResource(R.drawable.lens_dead)
                    }
                  fixedProgress in 8..50 -> {
                     Color.YELLOW
                     bindingClass.imgLensActing.setImageResource(R.drawable.lens_damaged)
                    }
                  else -> {
                     Color.GREEN
                     bindingClass.imgLensActing.setImageResource(R.drawable.lens_happy)

Comment: And one more thing. Can you please explain how it works? I mean these "progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf()". I can't understand why we use it and where we saving color. I'm so newbee :(

Comment: UPD. I figured it out :)

Comment: Glad that you make it work. I'm not sure if you still need an answer for the previous problem but if it worked probably not :)

Comment: Yeah thank you. I was stucked when i was needed to check color to put new image in my ImageView, but i figured out about how it actually put color in progressBar and how to check what we have in there.